# Parent object to bone latency (lag) issue

Tags: bones, parent, rigify

I'm using Pitchipoy meta rig and have come across instances where I need to parent an object or objects to a bone - I can't be the only one. Every time I do I get a latency issue where the child will lag behind the transform of the parenting bone which gives and undesired deform result.

[image]

This occurs when I use my mouse scroll wheel to scrub through the timeline. It also renders like this. It also shows when I scrub the timeline and prior to releasing the mouse button and once I do release the child snaps to the desired location.

What is the proper method for parenting objects to a Pitchipoy rig?

I'm thinking that there may be a hack where I can take advantage of parse order to cause the child to snap to its intended transform, like it does with the mouse button release, that I can do prior to rendering.

v2.76

Comment: Check for parenting dependency issues inside system console window. 99% of cases it will be this problem.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in console. It may not be a parenting issue error because of the "mouse button release" fix.

Comment: Then if there are no dependency cycles and yet blender fails to properly update the scene I would consider sending a bug report. Can you recreate the problem in a simple example and share it for evaluation?

Comment: Thanks Jerryno for your help. I'm going to try one last approach before I post a bug report. I suspect my method for parenting the facial tracking post Rigify generate is the cause. If I can resolve it I will post an answer.

Comment: I just posted a video of my issue. I hope that this clarifies things. I hope too that this video shows that I'm doing something drastically wrong [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAPL_eynwTw

Answer (score 3):

I searched the bug report and the file you provided there. There is indeed a dependency cycle on object level - it prints out into the system console:

[image]

The culprit is that the empty is parented to the head. Blender checks dependency cycles on object level in old dependency graph, which is a known limitation.

To solve the issue switch to the new dependency graph by running blender with `--enable-new-depsgraph` command line argument. It will work there, because blender evaluates dependencies better and on bone level.

Comment: Apologies - it does indeed!

Comment: Your a legend @Jerryno!