# My mesh won't deform with rig until after I click

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

So I was confused because my mesh didn't look like it was deforming with my rig, like I parented it wrong or maybe there was a missing Armature Modifier. But it's all there (And I cleared and repeated the parenting process like four times). So I tried to move it again, and happened to click to accept the bone placement, and ONLY THEN the mesh moved to fit the Rig. Why is this not moving live with the Rig like normal?

Thanks.

[Youtube Video of my prob.](https://youtu.be/_9re1H9V8Rg)

Comment: Try this http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50655/2517

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parent object to bone latency (lag) issue](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50498/parent-object-to-bone-latency-lag-issue)

Comment: check to be sure that slow parent is not turned on.